# Why is the following statement executing without errors?

Tags: javascript

```
var loop = function() 
{
    outer: for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
         for( var j=3;j>i; j--)
        {
           if( j == i)
              {
                 break
                 outer;
              }     
            alert("j: " + j);
       }
    }
};
```

The code runs fine and gives an output of 3,2,1,3,2,3.

It's understood that interpreter is automatically inserting semicolon after break statement, as 'outer' label is on the next line. But my point is, 'outer' is not an expression or statement but just a label. It can't be written individually, and therefore must be written either with **continue** or with **break** statement. So why instead of giving out an error, code is running perfectly fine?

Comment: Because outer is on the next line, does not mean that there is a semicolon inserted. The line will be interpreted as `break outer;`, not `break; outer;`

Comment: Output is same with or without `outer;`

Comment: @Ricconnect: Nope, it will not. [ES5 explicitly requires a semicolon insertion here](http://es5.github.io/#x12.8). Those two lines are two statements.

Answer (score 3):

> The code runs fine

I think your example would be much better if the condition was actually met and the break statement was executed. As your inner loops runs only to `j>i`, they will never be equal. Maybe change that to `>=`.

> 'outer' is not an expression or statement but just a label.

Nope. On it's own line,

```
outer;
```

is just an expression statement consisting of a single variable. Admittedly, that variable is undeclared and would throw an exception on being evaluated, but as the statement in front of it already returns control to the loop, it actually never is evaluated.